# Fallback to manifest file if support for serviceworkers is not supported

Tags: html, service-worker, offline-caching, cache-manifest, browser-feature-detection

I am making an app which will support the "Add to Homescreen" features in Android Chrome and iOS Safari. Since I would like universal offline support for both of these features, but I only want to use the manifest file where I have to, in order increase my control. However, iOS Safari does not support service workers, so my question is **how can I only instantiate a cache manifest file if support for Service Workers is not present**, more specifically; I know  I could add `manifest='whatever.appcache'` to the `<html>` tag with JavaScript, but will browsers, specifically iOS Safari, use that cache?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36727965/3591628

Comment: @DanielHerr Huh, that was useful. Thanks!

Comment: this is an excellent design! (Service Worker with fallback to AppCache)

Comment: Thanks @code_monk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to an [answer by @Daniel Herr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36727965/3591628):

> You could choose to use Service Workers and AppCache on the same web app. What happens in such a case is that browsers that don’t support Service Workers will use AppCache, and those that do will ignore the AppCache and let the Service Worker take over.
>
> Sources: https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#activation-algorithm, https://crbug.com/410665

Thanks for your answer!